# Formula for the divergence of a tensor

Tags: vectors, tensors, divergence-operator

I need to express the divergence of a tensor $\nabla \cdot (a \times b)$  to a different form.

I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_of_the_Navier%E2%80%93Stokes_equations#Conservation_of_momentum) that  $$\nabla \cdot (a \times b) = (\nabla \cdot a)b + a \cdot \nabla b$$ which is exactly what I'm looking for. However, I also [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Divergence) that $$\nabla \cdot (a \times b) = b(\nabla \cdot a) + (a \cdot \nabla) b$$

I'm wondering is those 2 expressions are the same or there is something else I don't understand.

Comment: The two expressions are the same. Note that the inner product of the gradient operator acting on vector $a$ yields a scalar (namely the divergence of $a$), therefore it can be placed either in front or behind the vector $b$. The result is the same. In the second term on the RHS brackets are placed, but this is merely for clarity.

Comment: Note that on the LHS you write an outer product, but it should be dyadic product. These are very different things. One is a vector, the other a tensor.